# Visual Basic - How do I share my program?

Tags: windows

I am currently in the process of developing a program in Visual Basic.  For now, I want to give the program to a few friends to test, make changes and then release it.  But I don't exactly know how.  I used the Publish feature in Visual Basic, but I don't exactly know what I'm supposed to do with it.  It mentions things like installing from a disk and whatnot.  I just plan to upload it to a file sharing website and release it that way.

EDIT: Using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: May be VB version or something?

Comment: I added my version in the OP

Comment: Try using version control? Edit: Oh, that's *you* "[making] changes."

Comment: Yeah, my friends don't know anything about programming so they are just gonna test the program.

Answer (score 0):

Use dropbox or any file sharing site :D

Comment: That was the plan but... where do I get the file from?  There's no .exe just sitting around anywhere.